# I Want to set My notification Alarm On next Day At around 9 but i am not able set

Tags: java, android, notifications

```
 Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent myInten = new Intent(Report_Activity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        final int intent_id_two = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Report_Activity.this.getSystemService(Report_Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Report_Activity.this, intent_id_two, myInten, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
        firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (firingCal.compareTo(now) < 0) {
            firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            myInten.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("date", str_view_date);
            bundle.putString("time", str_view_time);
            bundle.putString("school_name", str_show_school_name);
            bundle.putInt("intent_id", intent_id_two);
            myInten.putExtras(bundle);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, myPendingIntent);

        } else {
            myInten.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("date", str_view_date);
            bundle.putString("time", str_view_time);
            bundle.putString("school_name", str_show_school_name);
            bundle.putInt("intent_id", intent_id_two);
            myInten.putExtras(bundle);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, myPendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Here IS my Receiver Class

```
 int num = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        date = bundle.getString("date");
        time = bundle.getString("time");
        school_name = bundle.getString("school_name");
       // int notifyId = 1;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        //final int intent_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, num, notificationIntent, 0);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification From Dextro");
        builder.setContentText("Meeting Schedule at " + school_name + " on " + date + " and time is " + time);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.dextro_customerlogo);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);
        builder.setTicker("Notification From Dextro");
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("Meeting Schedule at " + school_name + " on " + date + " and time is " + time));
        builder.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 100, 100, 100});
        notificationManager.notify(num, builder.build());
//notifyId++;
    }
```

I want to set notification on next day but I am not receiving but when i set alarm for today then i am receiving notification.What should i do changes i this.If i set alarm within the range of 24 hr then i am receiving a notification  but when i go on next day to set an alarm then its not receiving please suggest me..

Comment: please help me i only want how can i get multiplication notification on status bar

Answer (score 0):

you have never used notifyID

```
notificationManager.notify(1/*Put it here*/, builder.build());
notifyId++;
```

Comment: why i am getting notifiacation in loop mean continous notification i receiving

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide new id for notification if you want to show new notification. If you leave same id you will update existing one.

**Actuall code from your question**

```
notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

**You need to replace 1 with notifyId**

```
notificationManager.notify(notifyId, builder.build());
notifyId++;
```

Comment: why i am getting notifiacation in loop mean continous notification i receiving